# How to take difference of several Timestamp series in a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timedelta

I want to obtain the timedelta interval between several timestamp columns in a dataframe. Also, several entries are NaN.

Original DF:

```
       0     1     2     3     4     5 
0    date1 date2  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    date3 date4 date5 date6 date7 date8
```

Desired Output:

```
          0           1           2           3           4
0    date2-date1     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1    date4-date3 date5-date4 date6-date5 date7-date6 date8-date7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use if consecutive `NaN`s to end of rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-01-02','2015-01-03', np.nan, np.nan],
                   ['2015-01-02','2015-01-05','2015-01-07','2015-01-12']])
print (df)
            0           1           2           3
0  2015-01-02  2015-01-03         NaN         NaN
1  2015-01-02  2015-01-05  2015-01-07  2015-01-12

df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime).ffill(axis=1).diff(axis=1)
print (df)
    0      1      2      3
0 NaT 1 days 0 days 0 days
1 NaT 3 days 2 days 5 days
```

**Details**:

First convert all columns to datetimes:

```
print (df.apply(pd.to_datetime))
           0          1          2          3
0 2015-01-02 2015-01-03        NaT        NaT
1 2015-01-02 2015-01-05 2015-01-07 2015-01-12
```

Replace `NaN`s by forward filling last value per rows:

```
print (df.apply(pd.to_datetime).ffill(axis=1))
           0          1          2          3
0 2015-01-02 2015-01-03 2015-01-03 2015-01-03
1 2015-01-02 2015-01-05 2015-01-07 2015-01-12
```

Get difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
print (df.apply(pd.to_datetime).ffill(axis=1).diff(axis=1))
    0      1      2      3
0 NaT 1 days 0 days 0 days
1 NaT 3 days 2 days 5 days
```